# Css div display above than page header

Tags: html, css

This div is display above than header page. How to fix it ?

[image]

Here's code for css in div section, I just put this code in html page

> /* The main DIV for the map */
>
> ```
> .subway-map
> {
>     margin: 0;
>     width: 500px;
>     height:410px;
>     background-color: white;
> }
>
> /* Text labels */
> .text
> {
>     text-decoration: none;
>     color: black;
>
> }
>
> #legend
> {
>     float: left;
>     width: 250px;
>     height:400px;
> }
>
> #legend div
> {
>     height: 25px;
> }
>
> #legend span
> {
>     margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
> }
> .subway-map span
> {
>     width: 200px !important;
> }
> ```

Comment: Probably one of them have position other than relative. Share the code...

Comment: share the css code

Comment: I already added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change the z-index in header, ex:

```
header {
z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I just realize that's div css  use z-index: 3000 in javascript file. therefore, i just edited the javascript file to change this part.

Answer (score -1):

Double check all of your tags and make sure they're all closed out. It seems that these are two separate components so they need to be in two separate tags.

e.g.

```
<div class="header">
    <!-- content goes here -->
</div>

<div class="section-1"> 
    <!-- content goes here -->
</div>

<div class="section-2"> 
    <!-- content goes here -->
</div>

.
.
.
```